# Creating a Singleton class with builder capabilities

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, builder

Consider the following hypothetical Singleton class `DateSingleton` which currently looks like the following:

```
public class DateSingleton {

  private static DateSingleton instance = new DateSingleton();

  private String year;
  private String month;
  private String day;

  private DateSingleton() {
  }

  public static DateSingleton getInstance(){
    return instance;
  }
}
```

This Singleton can be thought of as a date keeper, and only one of them will exist for my entire web application.  I would like to be able to make the following type of builder-style call to assign my state:

```
DateSingleton.getInstance().year("2015").month("February").day("25");
```

Can someone suggest what code I would need to add to the `DateSingleton` class in order to make this possible?  Is it considered bad practice to make a Singleton a builder?

I realize that I could just add getters and setters to accomplish the same funtionality.  But I want to move away from this, as there may be many properties in this Singleton and the builder pattern makes the code much easier to use and read.

Comment: why not create it with same parameters in DateSingleton constructor?

Comment: One of the motivations for using a builder is that it frees the consumer of the class from having to deal with complex constructors.  Also, the values in this bean will change over time, after instantiation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Values which change over time but which are global scare me. What if one thread calls `.day("25").month("February")` and another thread calls `.month("January").day("30")`? You could easily end up with February 30th... You should think *really* carefully about mutable global state. It's usually a timebomb waiting to go off.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the very prompt and thorough answer.  You made me realize that I need to rethink my design.  What I really want is along the lines of a stateless singleton with a utility method which consumes a stateful bean.

Answer (score 3):

Well If you want to do just that you could easily use :

```
public class DateSingleton {

    private static DateSingleton instance = new DateSingleton();

    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;
    public DateSingleton year(String year){
        this.year = year;
        return this;
    }
    public DateSingleton month(String month){
        this.month = month;
        return this;
    }
    public DateSingleton day(String day){
        this.day = day;
        return this;
    }
    private DateSingleton() {
    }

    public static DateSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

also, if you want to use builder pattern to force validity of the building process to avoid having you singleton in invalid states :

```
public class DateSingleton {

    private static DateSingleton instance = new DateSingleton();

    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;
    public static class Builder {
        private String year;
        private String month;
        private String day;
        public Builder year(String year){
            this.year = year;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder month(String month){
            this.month = month;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder day(String day){
            this.day = day;
            return this;
        }
        public DateSingleton build() {
            if (valid()) {
                instance.year=year;
                instance.day=day;
                instance.month=month;
                return instance;
            } else throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid creation");

        }
    }


    private DateSingleton() {
    }

    public static DateSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate "I only need one value for my whole web service" from "this class should be a singleton". The latter is one *possible* implementation, but it's certainly not the only one.

I assume this is part of some configuration data somewhere. You can separate the "getting at configuration" from the configuration class, to start with. For example, you could have:

```
// TODO: Validation and thread-safety; see below
public final class ConfigurationHolder {
    private static Configuration configuration;

    public static void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
        ConfigurationHolder.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public static ConfigurationHolder getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

You'd then want appropriate synchronization, validation that by the time `getConfiguration` is called, the configuration has been set, and probably validation that it's *only* set once, with maybe a `resetForTest` method which does what it says on the tin.

At this point, `Configuration` can be an immutable type with an appropriate builder - in your web app startup code, you'd build it with the builder, then set it, and then access it elsewhere.

*Better* in my view would be to use dependency injection to avoid having this global "holder" state in the first place. With dependency injection, in place, your startup code would still create the appropriate configuration using a builder, and then tell the DI framework that that's the configuration to use everywhere. Anything that *needed* a `Configuration` would then get presented it at the appropriate time.

My experience is that that leads to clearer, more testable code.